# How to set an sms app as default app in android programmatically

Tags: android

I have developed an android app for receiving sms from a particular number . It can marks sms as read from that number . TO mark sms as read , the application needs to be set as default . How can I set an app as default in android programmatically ?

Comment: I would imagine you can't without the users consent.

Comment: I want to do it with users consent .

Answer (score 7):

As I understand you need to ask the user to set your app as the default messaging app while launching your App. To do that use below code:

Set below `intent-filter` to activity which you want to show. In this case I have considered  "DefaultSMSAppChooserActivity"

```
<activity android:name=".DefaultSMSAppChooserActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MESSAGING" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Call below method to show all available messaging app on his/her device including yours to choose from as default.

```
public static void openSMSappChooser(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, DefaultSMSAppChooserActivity.class);
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING);
    selector.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(selector);

    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

You can use the above method anywhere as per your requirement.

Hope this helps you!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

Third party developers cannot set their own app as default applications. Only the users of your app can do this on their own device.

Anyway you can register your app to act as a messaging application through intent-filter

Comment: it is allowed, but user permission is required for this.

Comment: Its is absolutely allowed under user consent. but you have to implement all functionalities in your app to be qualify for default app.

For example: if you don't have compose message functionality in your app how is it possible you can make it default.

Answer (score 4):

Declare this in your Manifest file

```
<intent-filter >
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="application/sms" />
</intent-filter>
```

I am not sure of the mime type but please check the proper mime type for messaging since it is very important.

Comment: No just in your Manifest

Answer (score 4):

You can copy paste the manifest from officiall google messenger to check if it is working [link](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="vnd.android-dir/mms-sms" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 4):

The old method will not run on android 10 these are the code you can use to request for becoming default app

**Request to become default in android 10**
**For java developer**

```
    public void makeMyAppDefaultRequest(String packageName){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        RoleManager roleManager =getSystemService(RoleManager.class);
        if (roleManager.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)) {
            if (roleManager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)) {
                requestPermission()
            } else {
                Intent intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
            }
        } else {
            
        }
    } else {
        if (Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this).equals(packageName)) {

        } else {
            Intent intent =new  Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
            intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
        }
    }
}
```

**For Kotlin developer**

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val roleManager = getSystemService(RoleManager::class.java)
        if (roleManager!!.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)) {
            if (roleManager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)) {
                askPermissions()
            } else {
                val intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)
                startActivityForResult(intent, MAKE_DEFAULT_APP_REQUEST)
            }
        } else {
            toast(R.string.unknown_error_occurred)
            finish()
        }
    } else {
        if (Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this) == packageName) {
            askPermissions()
        } else {
            val intent = Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT)
            intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName)
            startActivityForResult(intent, MAKE_DEFAULT_APP_REQUEST)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working for me in api 33

Answer (score 2):

### Updated from 2023

As the doc here https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/role/RoleManagerCompat#ROLE_SMS() when you define these kind of components in manifest, system will treat your app as SMS role:

```xml
<activity>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="smsto" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<service android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="smsto" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<receiver android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And also don't forget define the permissions:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly spawn the framework's dialog to ask for making your app as the default messaging app, from inside your app, using the following `Intent` with `startActivity` :-

```
startActivity(Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT).putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force this, and you shouldn't be able to. What you can do is make known your app can open the file type. The user gets the standard "what program do you wish to use" dialog, and the user can select something as default. If the user has already selected a default, he/she needs to undo that before the dialog appears (obviously, otherwise a 'default' wouldn't have a lot of effect, now would it?)